# Is this right way to convert data attributes values to number in javascipt? Need to get valid numeric value or 0

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the following code to convert data attribute values to Numbers. I want to get a valid numeric value or 0 in all cases. e.g if the data attribute value is blank("") then I need 0 in that case. The intention is to avoid getting NaN because I am using the result in calculations.

```js
Number($("td[id^='tdCumulativeUnderOverSpendPrevious']").data("val") || 0);
```

Comment: jQuery will do the Number conversion for you, usually.

Comment: Can you please adjust your Code Snippet with HTML and pick the version of jQuery you use to show the problem that you are trying to solve?

Comment: The intention is to avoid getting NaN because I am using the result in calculations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend moving the `|| 0` to the outside of the `Number()` call. You want to convert the element's data to a number, so you should pass only that into `Number()`. `Number()` will return `NaN` if that value can't be parsed, and only then do you want to change the whole thing into `0`.

Using `|| 0` inside of the `Number()` call might have unintended consequences depending because it will change any [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) value into zero, not just a value that can't be converted to a number.

Also, consider using [`parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) instead of `Number()`. `Number()` will convert any value that can possible be converted, however `parseFloat()` is stricter. For example, `Number(true)` is `1`, but `parseFloat(true)` is `NaN`.

Here's the code that I'd use:

```js
// set data to number
$('div').data('val', '100')

const num1 = parseFloat($('div').data('val')) || 0;
console.log(num1);

// set data to not a number
$('div').data('val', 'hello')

const num2 = parseFloat($('div').data('val')) || 0;
console.log(num2);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div></div>
```

Comment: The original “falsy things will become zero” is *better* than “falsy things will become zero or NaN then become zero, *and* any truthy thing that’s not a number will become zero”. Solves the same problem, fails more obviously when the input is unexpected.

Comment: In re: `parseFloat()`, it will happily parse "123hello world" (as `123`). Something like `Number(String(source))` is a little better.